# Using a String or File class when dealing with files

Tags: java, string, file

Should the `File` class be used systematically when dealing with files or are there cases where it's ok to use `String`s to represent the path and filename?

Comment: Sometimes a [URI](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/net/URI.html) might be appropriate as well.

Comment: If you're on Java 7, look into `Path`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you take a look at the various file stream / reader / writer classes that take either a `String` or `File`, you'll see that the constructor that takes a `String` is convenience overload for the constructor that takes a `File`.  In other words, the `String` constructor typically creates a `File` from the pathname string and calls the other constructor.

So using the `File` version potentially saves constructing new File objects.

On the other hand, a `File` instance will occupy more memory than the equivalent `String`, and the cost of creating a `File` instance is small compared with the cost of opening and reading / writing a file.

The bottom line is that it probably doesn't matter for a small-scale application from a performance perspective.  With a large scale application the *most appropriate approach* depends on what the application is actually doing; e.g. whether or not it is repeatedly using the same files.

---

And as the comments say, there are other ways to "denote" files / paths as well; e.g. "file:" URLs and the Java 7 `Path` class.

Answer (score 1):

A `File` instance represents a path on the local file system. If that's what you want your variable to be, it's the appropriate class to use. If not (like a simple file name, or a file path on another machine), use something else.

Answer (score 1):

The File class is just that, a class. You can construct it with a string representing the path to the file. But it requires an additional action to do something with the file. That is when you'll most likely incur most of your performance cost. File IO, stream reading, or writing, etc. You can use this class to look up file information including permissions.

If you're not doing one of those actions, then you should consider one of the other alternatives mentioned in this thread.